# form submit refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below working fine in my local PC and local Publish. But when I publish it on another PC as PC Server code below is refresh the page after I click the button log-in.

I also tried the following events `e.stopPropagation(), e.stopimmediatepropagation()` but it keeps refreshing the page.

**JS**

```
 $("#frmVerification").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $("#frmVerification");
    elem.find('.loading').removeClass('hidden');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../Account/Verify',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'get',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.success) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.replace(res.url);
                }, 1000);
            } 
            elem.find('.loading').addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
})
```

**HTML**

```
   <form id="frmVerification">
    <div class="card-header bg-success-origin">
        <div class="card-title">
            <label>Login Verification</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <label>Verification Code</label>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase font-weight-bold" name="VerificationCode" placeholder="ENTER VERIFICATION CODE" disabled />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" id="btnResendEmail" class="btn btn-flat rounded-right" disabled><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pr-lg-4 pl-lg-4 col-lg-4 mt-4 text-lg-right text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" disabled>Submit<i class="fa fa-refresh loading hidden"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger hidden" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom:-20px;background: #94040b26">
            <ul id="divVerificationAlert"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: perhaps the form doesn't yet exist in the DOM when `$("#frmVerification").on('submit'` is executed ... is the javascript above or below the form in the document? try enclosing it in `$(function() { ... put the code here... })` to wait for the document to fully load before trying to add a submit handler

Comment: that's one of the biggest negatives to jQuery ... if a selector fails to match anything, it is not an "error"

Comment: your code is perfectly fine. Just try the another browser.

Comment: @MuhammadAftab i test in Microsoft Edge. Still the same

Comment: why are you using `disabled` with `<button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" disabled>Submit<i class="fa fa-refresh loading hidden"></i></button>`

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this.

```
<form id="frmVerification" onsubmit="return false">
```